# Using openssl alternate config file from bash?

Tags: openssl

I would not like (or cannot) modify the default .cnf openssl config file.

How do tell the openssl command line tool to use a different .cnf file at another location - not the default?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can override openssl configuration using one of the actions:

- Set `OPENSSL_CONF` environment variable to point to your custom configuration file
- Use `-config` option with the commands handling certificate (e.g. `req`, `ca`...)
- Most of the definition in the `openssl.cnf` can be overridden using command line option.

You can also look at `man x509v3_config`.

Comment: could you please post some samples of syntax putting parameters from config file to command line? openssl.cnf use cryptic syntax with dollar signs (never seen in windows world) and I cant found eny example of how to transcript to command line. For example what parameters are mandatory for what actions (req, ca, etc..)

Comment: @user2956477: You can use the subj parameter as follows: `openssl req -new -sha256 -key keyFile.pem -out csrRequest.csrr -subj "/C=US/ST=OH/L=Cincinnati/O=Your Company, Inc./OU=IT/CN=yourdomain.com"`