# How to override a parameter in an openssl configuration file using the cli?

Tags: openssl

I'm using freeradius for EAP-TLS authentication.

I run this command to generate the key:
`openssl req -new  -out client.csr -keyout client.key -config ./client.cnf`

I'd like to generate several keys/certificates for different users changing:

- `emailAddress` and `commonName` under `[client]`
- `input_password` and `output_password` under `[ req ]`

**Question:** Is there a parameter of the `openssl` command to override the configuration file?

I'm thinking using `sed` if there is no other solution.

**/etc/freeradius/3.0/certs# cat client.cnf**:

```
[ ca ]
default_ca      = CA_default

[ CA_default ]
dir         = ./
certs           = $dir
crl_dir         = $dir/crl
database        = $dir/index.txt
new_certs_dir       = $dir
certificate     = $dir/ca.pem
serial          = $dir/serial
crl         = $dir/crl.pem
private_key     = $dir/ca.key
RANDFILE        = $dir/.rand
name_opt        = ca_default
cert_opt        = ca_default
default_days        = 365
default_crl_days    = 30
default_md      = sha256
preserve        = no
policy          = policy_match

[ policy_match ]
countryName     = match
stateOrProvinceName = match
organizationName    = match
organizationalUnitName  = optional
commonName      = supplied
emailAddress        = optional

[ policy_anything ]
countryName     = optional
stateOrProvinceName = optional
localityName        = optional
organizationName    = optional
organizationalUnitName  = optional
commonName      = supplied
emailAddress        = optional

[ req ]
prompt          = no
distinguished_name  = client
default_bits        = 4096
input_password      = clientpassword
output_password     = clientpassword

[client]
countryName     = JP
stateOrProvinceName = Tokyo
localityName        = Company building
organizationName    = Company name
emailAddress        = testuser@company.com
commonName      = testuser@company.com
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found these two options to override variables in the configuration file:

1. Most of the definitions in `openssl.cnf` can be overridden using command-line options, as [this answer suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37943865/3761766). However, I am not sure if this applies to the variables you mention.
2. When running the OpenSSL CLI, the environment is mapped onto a section called ENV.  By using the form `$ENV::name` environment variables can be substituted in any other section. This information comes from the [OpenSSL documentation (config - OpenSSL CONF library configuration files)](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man5/config.html).

Regarding the second method, [this config file](https://pki-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/simple/server.conf.html) reads the `subjectAltName` variable in `[ server_reqext ]` section from the `SAN` environment variable.